# In "One to Many" Mapping hibernate data is getting inserted in child table while updating parent table

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

```
                import java.util.Set;
                import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
                import javax.persistence.Column;
                import javax.persistence.Entity;
                import javax.persistence.FetchType;
                import javax.persistence.Id;
                import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
                import javax.persistence.Table;

                @Entity
                @Table(name="BILLING_INFORMATION")
                public class BillingInformation {

                    @Id
                    @Column(name="BILL_NO", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
                    private String bNo;

                    @Column(name="BILL_DATE", length = 100)
                    private String billDate;

                    @Column(name="PARTY_NAME", length = 100)
                    private String partyName;

                    @Column(name="SUB_TOTAL", length = 100)
                    private String subTotal;

                    @Column(name="TOTAL", length = 100)
                    private String total;

                    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="billInformation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
                    Set<BillingItemInformation> setBillingItemInformation;

                    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="billInformation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,orphanRemoval=true)
                    Set<BillingTaxInformation> setBillingTaxInformation;

            ----all getters and setters----
            }


        import javax.persistence.Column;
        import javax.persistence.Entity;
        import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
        import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
        import javax.persistence.Id;
        import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
        import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
        import javax.persistence.Table;

        @Entity
        @Table(name="BILLING_ITEM_INFORMATION")
        public class BillingItemInformation {


            @Id
            @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
            @Column(name = "RECORD_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
            private int recordNo;

            @Column(name = "S_NO", length = 100)
            private String sNo;

            @Column(name="ITEM", length = 100)
            private String item;

            @Column(name="QTY", length = 100)
            private String qty;

            @Column(name="PRICE", length = 100)
            private String price;

            @Column(name="AMOUNT", length = 100)
            private String amount;

            @ManyToOne
            @JoinColumn(name="BILL_NO", nullable=false)
            private BillingInformation billInformation;

        ---all getters and setters----

    }

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="BILLING_TAX_INFORMATION")
public class BillingTaxInformation {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "RECORD_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 100)
    private int recordNo;

    @Column(name = "TAX_NAME", length = 100)
    private String taxName;

    @Column(name = "TAX_PERCENTAGE", length = 100)
    private String taxInPercent;

    @Column(name = "TAX_AMOUNT", length = 100)
    private String taxAmount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="BILL_NO", nullable=false)
    BillingInformation billInformation;
--------all getters and setters----
}
```

I just started learning hibernate from simple java jdbc and as part of our project requirement I have to maintain above three classes but when I am updating BillingInformation.java entity class object then BillingTaxInformation.java and BillingItemInformation.java class object get inserted the same object with different recordNo. Please correct me where I am doing mistake.

Comment: post the hashcode & equals method of all entities. It's possibly because the Id field may be null when it is first loaded in the collection.

Comment: Where is th code for updating an instance of `BillingInformation`? The mapping seems to be OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using cascade = CascadeType.ALL in both @OneToMany mappings of your Sets.

This means that whatever operation done on the BillingInformation entity, will be propagate also to the child BillingItemInformation and BillingTaxInformation.

That is when you

- PERSIST
- REFRESH
- MERGE
- REMOVE
- DETACH

.. the same would be applied to these children.

If you only want to cascade when the parent entity is

- PERSISTED(or saved in the hibernate language)
- and DELETED (two most common options for @OneToMany)

, but during MERGE and subsequent update, you do not want to cascade those operations to children then set-up you mappings as follows:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="billInformation"
          , cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }
          ,orphanRemoval=true)
Set<BillingItemInformation> setBillingItemInformation;

@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="billInformation"
         , cascade ={ CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE }
         ,orphanRemoval=true)
Set<BillingTaxInformation> setBillingTaxInformation;
```

**Update**

With hibernate annotation you would configure as follows:

```
@Cascade({CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DELETE})
```

Comment: You mean probably `CascadeType.REMOVE`?

Comment: Correct.. with JPA it should be REMOVE.. delete is in hibernate annotation

Comment: @Maciej I also want to update child records when parent record gets updated but it should update the existing record rather than creating new record no for billingtaxinformation or billingiteminformation.

Comment: Do the records of the child entities come with ids? Are those ids already in dB? How do you do the update I want to see the code

Comment: This answer seems completely unrelated to the OP's problem.

Comment: Im not done yet mate.. more information has surfaced and i will make updates.. just dont have time to delve more into it during the weekend lol..